# Редактирование строк таблицы на js, как обновлять массив с объектами для отправки на бэк измененных строк?

Tags: javascript, массивы, vue.js, объекты

```
data() {
  return {
    changedOperationList: {}
  }
},
methods: {
  setChangesForRequest({name, value, item}) {
    let changedOperation = {};
    const businessOperationId = item.businessOperationId;

    changedOperation = {businessOperationId};
    changedOperation[name] = value;

    this.changedOperationList.push(changedOperation);
  },
}
```

У меня есть таблица, в которой при изменениях на селектах запускается метод setChangesForRequest, в который приходят name - имя колонки, value - новое значение селекта и item - строка в которой был изменен селект, из строки я беру айди и вставляю это все в объект Измененной операции (на скрине видно, как я меняю разные селекты и они возвращают объекты с разными ключами. Потом я эти объекты пушу в пустой массив (чтобы потом сделать запрос на бэк). Как мне, например, когда я у одной и той же строки меняю селекты они в один объект собирались, просто добавляли новый ключ и если этот ключ там есть обновить его новыми данными, их там может быть 3 штуки roleId, zoneId и technologyId. И вообще стоит ли так делать? В итоге у меня должен получится массив из отредактированных операций с полями, которые я изменял.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setChangesForRequest({name, value, item}) {
  const { businessOperationId :  id } = item;

  if( !this.changedOperationList[id] ) {
    this.changedOperationList[id] = {businessOperationId: id};
  }
  this.changedOperationList[id][name] = value;
},
```

Нашел решение данной проблемы... В итоге если ключ id будет совпадать с объектом создаваемым при изменении значения селекта, то он не будет создавать его, но зато будет прокидывать новые поля в объекты, в зависимости от столбца, где мы меняли селект.